# Extract a sentence from mail with Regex

Tags: r, regex, email, tags, extract

I need to extract with Regex a sentence without the tag `<br>` but it's give me issues with that.

```
 (?<=Status:) (.*)[^<br>]
```

Status: i3 Naviera indicates that the container is already released`<br>`

This sentence comes from an mail

```
 "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"
 content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\nStatus:
 i3 Naviera indicates that the container is already
 released<br>\r\nObservations:  data requested.<br>\r\n<br>\r\n<img
 src=\"http://test/logo/Logo2.png\">\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

I just need to extract:

i3 Naviera indicates that the container is already released

Comment: Maybe `sub(".*Status:(.*?)<br>.*", "\\1", "<html>..")

Comment: `regmatches(v, regexpr("Status:\\s*\\K[^<]+", v, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex would work for your content:

```
(?<=Status: )(.*?)(?=<br>)
```

It matches the `Status:` with space, and stops at the first `<br>` and does not include it in the match.

Please note that using regex for html parsing requires that the html content does not change much.

Comment: Thank you! now it's working!